# Ruby: Multithreading several MD5 digests with IO:popen subprocesses

Tags: ruby, multithreading, md5, popen

I need to calculate some MD5 of very large files (>1TB) for deduplication purposes. For example, I have a 10GiB file and want to simultaneously calculate the MD5 of the whole file and of each of the 10 sequential 1GiB chunks.

I cannot use the form:

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(IO.read("file_10GiB.txt"))
```

because Ruby first reads the whole file in memory before calculating the MD5, so I quickly run out of memory.

So I can read it in 1MiB chunks with the following code.

```
require "digest"

fd = File.open("file_10GiB.txt")
digest_1GiB = Digest::MD5.new
digest_10GiB = Digest::MD5.new
10.times do
  1024.times do
    data_1MiB = fd.read(2**20) # Each MiB is read only once so 
    digest_1GiB << data_1MiB   # there is no duplicate IO operations.
    digest_10GiB << data_1MiB  # It is then sent to both digests.
  end
  puts digest_1GiB.hexdigest
  digest_1GiB.reset
end
puts digest_10GiB.hexdigest
```

That takes around 40 seconds. The results are similar using `openssl` instead of `digest`.

If I comment out `digest_1GiB << data_1MiB` or `digest_10GiB << data_1MiB`, it unsurprisingly goes twice as fast (20 seconds) and the bash command `md5sum file_10GiB.txt` takes around 20 seconds, so that is consistent.

Clearly both MD5's are being calculated in the same thread and core so I thought I could use some multithreading. I'm using Ruby MRI 2.2.1 that doesn't have real multithreading but using subprocesses I can calculate the MD5's on several cores simultaneously:

```
fd = File.open("file_10GiB.txt")
IO.popen("md5sum", "r+") do |md5sum_10GiB|
  10.times do
    IO.popen("md5sum", "r+") do |md5sum_1GiB|
      1024.times do
        data_1MiB = fd.read(2**20) # Each MiB is read only once so 
        md5sum_1GiB << data_1MiB   # there is no duplicate IO operations.
        md5sum_10GiB << data_1MiB  # It is then sent to both digests.
      end
      md5sum_1GiB.close_write
      puts md5sum_1GiB.gets
    end
  end
  md5sum_10GiB.close_write
  puts md5sum_10GiB.gets
end
```

But this takes 120 seconds, three times slower. Why would that be?

Strangely, if I comment out `md5sum_1GiB << data_1MiB` or `md5sum_10GiB << data_1MiB` it doesn't take 60 seconds as expected, but 40, which is still half of the theoretical speed.

The results are similar using `Open3::popen2` instead of `IO::popen`. Same for `openssl md5` instead of `md5sum`.

I have confirmed the speed differences of those pieces of code with significantly larger files to make sure it wasn't insignificant measurement errors and the proportions stay the same.

I have very fast IO storage with about 2.5GiB/s sequential read so I don't think it could cause any limitations here.

Comment: I don't fully follow the code, but calculating an md5 is a I/O bound operation, so having lots of threads or processes might impact negatively the performance as a hard drives (in particular mechanical drives) are optimized for sequential read. If you run `top` can you see if most of the time is spent on `wait`?

Comment: I only read each MiB once with `data_1MiB = fd.read(2**20)` so there is no duplicate disk operation. Anyway I have very fast IO storage, so this has no effect there. Edited about that. In `top`, `wa` stays at 0 with both scripts.